# Getting NZEC error in python code on code chef

Tags: python, runtime-error, eoferror

I am trying to `input` in `code chef` compiler but am getting `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` error.

Code Chef Question:

Contest Code:JULY20B Problem Code:CHEFSTR1

Question URL - https://www.codechef.com/JULY20B/problems/CHEFSTR1

Error Image URL - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRIq3.png

Sample Input:

2

6

1 6 11 6 10 11

4

1 3 5 7

Sample Output:

15

3

My code:

```
T = int(input())
for item in range(T):

    [enter image description here][1]I = input().split(" ")
```

I am a beginner in coding so the help of any kind would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add code, errors, and data as text, not screenshots because [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It is likely the question will be down-voted. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible.

Comment: okay would definitely do that

Answer (score 0):

this will do to take input in the code problem

```
 t = int(input())
 for _ in range(t):
     n = int(input())
     lis_ = list(map(int, input().split()))
```